# How do I set an environment variable on Windows 10, which was generated from GitHub?

Tags: github, token, electron, git-bash, electron-builder

I want to make an updater for my Electron application, and I stuck on the GitHub access token.

I have generated a token from my GitHub account, and after that, I tried to set that token in my Windows environmental variables.

When I go to my application and I run this file **publish.sh**

#### publish.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$GH_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo "You must set the GH_TOKEN environment variable."
    echo "See README.md for more details."
    exit 1
fi

# This will build, package and upload the app to GitHub.
node_modules/.bin/build --win --mac -p always
```

I run this file ./publish.sh and I get this message:

> You must set the GH_TOKEN environment variable.

I want to achieve step 4 and 5 in this example:
https://github.com/iffy/electron-updater-example

I tried to run this command from the Git Bash `export GH_TOKEN="435468246872235283762846848267"`, but I get a return code of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set an environment variable on Windows 10, which was generated from GitHub?

Make sure to restart a new CMD session (in which you can type `bash`) in order to make sure your session does inherit the new Windows environment variable you have just set.

Once you have done that, you can check in the (new) Git Bash session which are the environment variables already set, with:

```
env
env | grep GH
```

Make sure your script starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The [OP George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6600549/george) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753339/how-i-can-assign-an-environment-variable-on-windows-github-access-token-set-va/42753422?noredirect=1#comment72629969_42753422) that the correct form is:

```
export GH_TOKEN=MY_VARIABLE_NAME
```

(no double quotes)

Comment: C:\Users\George\Desktop>git bash
git: 'bash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        stash

C:\Users\George\Desktop>  I type git bash inside gitbash and is say no such command the same inside cmd were i type this command ???

Comment: i type env and i find my variable

Comment: Then simply type bash

Comment: If you see your variable, then your script should work (although I recommend stating it with `#!/bin/bash`)

Comment: i make a big mistake i type GH_TOKEN="52462676/4762762587425"  and the right way was GH_TOKEN=MY_VARIABLE_NAME   no "" no numbers only the varible name that i create when i set it on windows variables :) but thnx bro for your help

Comment: @George Right! I have included that in the answer for more visibillity

Comment: OMG i dont refresh the page and i dont see that answer lol now i see that